# Pass all home audio through PC

Tags: audio, home-networking, audio-streaming

Just wondering if it is possible to pass all home audio that is connected to my TV through my PC for improved audio output?

Devices such as Xbox, PS4 etc. Everyone would be plugged into the one main TV which would act as a monitor for everything.

Comment: You want your TV audio out to be played via your PC?

Comment: Yea, along with anything that may be plugged into the TV

Comment: What speakers you have connected with your speakers 5.1?

Answer (score 1):

You would need some sort of pass through from your tv to your computer.

You could for example get a male-male audio jack cable. Plug one into your tv audio out (headphones) and the other one into your computer on an audio in (microphone). Then configure your system to playback from that audio in channel.

On windows this would selecting your microphone from the `Recording` devices, enable `Listen to this device.`

You could also use a digital signal if your tv has an output and your computer has an input. You could take a look at different sound cards with digital inputs for this.

Obviously, this link, depending on the quality, could be a bottleneck in your audio quality.

I made the assumption that the signals for microphone in and speakers out are the same here, but that sounds pretty reasonable.

Edit: Don't put it into microphone, but into line in, as per @Sassafras_wot's reply.

Comment: you would plug into the LINE IN jack on your computer, NOT the microphone jack.  LINE IN typically provides STEREO + 10K ohms impedance. MIC provides MONO + 600-1k ohm impedance. MIC expects drastically lower signal levels as it also typically has a preamp to pickup low mic levels.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, would you be able to ensure higher quality sound when routing sound through a PC vs. the native device's sound processing ability? Assuming that a quality sound card is used?